# VB ElseIf Statement Limited to 1

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I was forced by college to do a application in Visual Studio (Basic) and I never had expierence with this language before so I'm confused. I did `If` statement which is working and then I've added `EleseIf` which is also working but after I've added Second `ElseIf` it doesn't work. It seems like only `If` statement and the first `ElseIf` is working for me but I need more than just 1 `ElseIf` statement.

```
Public Class receipt
Private Sub receipt_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim outputValue As Decimal = My.Settings.outputamount.Remove(4)
    Dim calculation As Decimal = outputValue * My.Settings.inputamount
    Dim totalwithoutcharge As String = calculation.ToString
    customername.Text = "Name: " + My.Settings.Username
    Label6.Text = "Entered Money: " + My.Settings.inputamount + " " + My.Settings.currency
    Label7.Text = "Converted To: " + totalwithoutcharge + " " + My.Settings.outputcurrency

    If calculation < 100 Then
        Label8.Text = "Charge: 0%"
        Label9.Text = "Total: " + totalwithoutcharge + " " + My.Settings.outputcurrency
    ElseIf calculation > 100 Then
        Label8.Text = "Charge: 1%"
        Label9.Text = "Total: " + totalwithoutcharge + " " + My.Settings.outputcurrency
    ElseIf calculation > 500 Then
        Label8.Text = "Charge: 2%"
        Label9.Text = "Total: " + totalwithoutcharge + " " + My.Settings.outputcurrency
    ElseIf calculation > 1000 Then
        Label8.Text = "Charge: 3%"
        Label9.Text = "Total: " + totalwithoutcharge + " " + My.Settings.outputcurrency
    Else
        Label8.Text = "Something went wrong"
    End If
End Sub 
End Class
```

I've entered many values I've add over 600 and it was still showing 'Charge: 1%' where it should show 2% instead. The same happen with values higher than 1000 it will still show the 1%. But when the value is below 100 then is OK and it is showing 0%.

[Over 100 works fine too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYaqF.png)
[Over 500 doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhklB.png)

I've also tried to do it with two conditions where it would look at range but it didn't work too. 
I've tried 'ElseIf calculation > 100 And calculation > 500 Then' but there is no difference.

Comment: Do the checks in reverse order.  Currently > 100 catches everything that is not less than 100.  Your comparisons should probably be >=

Comment: because this is a logic problem, 600 is still > in 100. so it will go on 2 statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my comment

```
    If calculation >= 1000 Then

    ElseIf calculation >= 500 Then

    ElseIf calculation >= 100 Then

    Else
        'lass than 100
    End If
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all use & instead of + when concentating strings.
Second if calculation is > 500 it is also greater than 100, 200 etc. So you need to implement a range. So think about the logic.

Comment: Thank you I did as dbasnett suggest and it is working. Thank you for your time and all '+' are now replaced with '&'. Thank you.